# Oracle Error: stored procedure parameters values not declared

Tags: oracle11g

Following is the procedure code snippet:

```
PRC_UPDATE

BEGIN

UPDATE EMP E SET E.NAME = 'X' WHERE E.E_ID = 'Y';

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS 

ROLLBACK;

PRC_ERROR_LOG(E.E_ID,sqlcode,sqlerrm);

RAISE;

END PRC_UPDATE;
```

I have a procedure which updates the values in a table.I have defined an error logging procedure (`PRC_ERROR_LOG)`to insert the errors in an Error Logging Table.But while calling `PRC_ERROR_LOG` it throws an error as `"identifier 'E_ID' must be declared"`. Will it not recognize the Row value in which the error is thrown out.

Basically my requirement is to insert the error and the row where the particular error is caught into the error table .How can I send the particular Row value in the Error Logging Procedure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a cursor, the reason that you are experiencing this error is that you have already executed the update statement and the `e.e_id` is now out of scope.  You could also use [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to accomplish this.